# PrepareContainerForItemOverride works different in Desktop than in Mobile UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I wanted to change the color of an item of ListView according the data value.
It would be easy doing:

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType = "ListViewItem" >
         < Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding EventType, Converter={StaticResource EventTypeToBackColorConverter}}"  />
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But the thing is that UWP does not support binding in Setter Properties.
My second attempt was overriding PrepareContainerForItemOverride of the ListView:

```
public class EventListView : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        var listViewItem = element as ListViewItem;
        var ev = item as EventType;
        if(ev.Warning)
           listViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red);
    }
}
```

The above code works fine running in a PC with Windows 10 and UWP. It colors in red some items according the underlying data. When I run the same app in Windows Mobile, at beginning it works fine, but when I scroll up and then I scroll down, returning to the original view that was ok at beginning, now other items are also in red color.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the reason, but the following code works for me:

```
public class EventListView : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        var listViewItem = element as ListViewItem;
        var ev = item as EventType;
        if(ev.Warning)
           listViewItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red);
        else
           listViewItem.Background = null;
    }
}
```

I have added `listViewItem.Background = null`

Answer (score 0):

This is because when there are a large number of Items, by default `ListView` has implement the function of data virtualization. It's not a good idea to disable this function since it can achieve a better performance.

But for your scenario, there is a much easier method to solve your problem. Since you're trying to modify the style of `ListViewItem` in the code behind, and we can't modify the existed one, we can set a new style of `ListViewItem` to `ListView` for example like this:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dynamicStyle = new Style();
    dynamicStyle.TargetType = typeof(ListViewItem);
    dynamicStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Colors.Red));
    listView.ItemContainerStyle = dynamicStyle;
}
```

Only one problem is, if you are setting the `Background` property to all the `ListViewItem`, it makes no difference than binding data to the `Background` property of `ListView` or setting the `Background` to `ListView` like this:

```cs
listView.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

So I just assume that you want to modify the root control in the `DataTemplate` for example like the `Grid` in the following xaml:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind collection}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Name="myListItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Testtext}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in this scenario, you can use data binding probably like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{Binding EventType, Converter={StaticResource EventTypeToBackColorConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Testtext}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any way, if you insist to change some property of all `ListViewItem` in the `ListView`, you can use the first method I provided.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The thing is that each item could have a different color, so ListView.Background  would not be a solution. The second option, using DataTemplate, did not work for me because the color does not fill the entire rectangle, like the selection. There is a margin.